# What does "royal adventure" spin mean in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In the main menu, after clicking RP in the top right corner, this "royal adventure" panel opens:

[image: Screenshot of PUBG Mobile - Royale Adventure Shop]

So I select the bike, I hit the "start" button to purchase this bike, but this spin appears:

[image: Screenshot of PUBG Mobile - Royale Adventure MiniGame]

What does "royal adventure" spin mean in PUBG?

Answer (score 1):

Royale Adventure is a board game style minigame within the PUBG store. You use RP Badges, obtained by upgrading your Royale Pass Rank, to start the game and spin the wheel. After you begin the game, you may choose to pay RP to guarantee your advance, or play for free for a random chance of failing. You will arrive at stations where you are given Adventure Supplies as rewards, which are used to purchase items in the Royale Adventure shop. You can choose to collect the rewards at the station, or continue advancing. If you decide to continue to advance through the adventure, you have a random chance of succeeding the event, and advancing, or a failing outcome will be selected based on the event triggered.

There is no cost if the player chooses to advance and succeeds, but if the player fails they will lose some supplies and this round of the adventure will be lost. You can choose to use more RP to do a Guided Advance, which will guarantee advancement at least 3 times at the same station. This cost increases as the adventure advances.

You can choose at any point to collect your rewards, which will instantly cash out all supplies and reset your progress in the adventure. If at any point during the adventure you fail to advance, you will lose the number of supplies equal to the rewards at either the furthest two stations (75%) or single furthest station (25%) you have reached in the current round of the adventure. For example, if you've made it to station 4 and fail to advance, you will lose either 95 or 133 of the 153 supplies you have collected, leaving you with a 75% chance of having 58 supplies or a 25% chance of having 20 supplies gained from the adventure.

You have a 20% chance of succeeding the adventure if you choose to advance for free throughout the entire round. Adventure Supplies will expire at the end of the event.

You can access this information within the app by clicking on the question mark (?) next to the label stating when the date ends in the top left of the app, under Royale Adventure, pictured here:

[image: Screenshot of PUBG Mobile - Royale Adventure MiniGame]